# Capacitors getting too Hot

Tags: capacitor, electrolytic-capacitor

I have parallel Inductor and Capacitor like below. This is a one part of the circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4bGpF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I want to have sinusoidal current on waveform. Everything is ok. But in the circuit, @ the output of the capacitor voltage is changing, it is like fallowing sine wave. Cap input is fixed and 12V, so that capacitor getting too hot. Is there any additional circuit to prevent it. Full circuit diagram and its' explanation is below.
[image: Proteus Drawing]
[image: PCB Image]

9837 is a Sinewave generator and connected to Nano 1 to set frequency. It's output goes to LM358 to amplify it to desired voltage level. And with 4131, i am playing with digital potentiometer that is directly connected to LM358(U1) amplifier circuit to obtain desired gain. At the end I have pure sinusoidal waveform that i can play with its' peak voltage which goes through the IRF3205 gate pin. So with this sinusoidal waveform, i have sinusoidal magnetic wave on inductor.And these capacitors will be parallel with inductor for some frequency range to get close pure sinusoidal magnetic waveform. Each capacitors working with its' frequency range. For example, if i choose to work with 2500Hz, 1uF will be choosen only. Controlling relays with Nano 2, actually doing that. Almost everything working fine. However, @ the choosen capacitors' negative side, there is a voltage changing that fallowing the gate of the tranistor. Positive side is fixed and 12V. It causes current flow from - side to the + side of the capacitor. So capacitor getting too hot. I couldn't solve this issiue.

NOTE:

I am using electrolytic capacitors.

- 2500 - 2000Hz << 1uF
- 2000 - 800 Hz << 10uF
- 800 - 500 Hz << 47uF
- 500 - 300 Hz << 100uF
- 300 - 100 Hz << 220uF

'-' side of these capacitors are connected directly drain of IRF3205 Do you think sin wave on gate has any effect @ - side of capacitors ?

Comment: calculate the complex currents that flow through C and L. Then, get the datasheet for these components, and try to estimate the losses (dielectric losses and ESR in the C, ohmic resistance in the L) based on these currents and the fact P=I²·R

Comment: At what frequency?

Comment: If this isn't the "full circuit diagram", then what is the point of the question? If you want any meaningful answers, you need to provide *ALL* of the relevant details in your question.

Comment: I hope you wisely choose a cap with low Dissipation Factor such as 0.005

Comment: I would assume a film capacitor...what dielectric?  If polyester, switch to polypropylene.

Comment: What kind of capacitors are you using? Units with ratings of tens or hundreds of uF are usually polarized, but you need nonpolarized capacitors in this application.

Comment: @RobertEndl i am using upto 330uF. These polypropylene capacitors are available in the Market ?
Is it possible to find nonpolarized capacitors that has values up to 330uF in Market ?

Comment: do you have realistic design specs?  do you have ANY specs?

Comment: it looks like an overly complicated sine generator with  digital selected cap for some tank cct that could be driven by a low RdsOn voltage source for a parallel tank resulting low Q. unsure what purpose , as the L is missing on the schematic. Perhaps trying to learn about SRF effects and heating effects on polarized caps with alternating  voltage.  ( NOT a GOOD IDEA) Anyone want to guess the intent?  But if pulsed then it would ring at resonance.

Comment: Your schem. says 1 uF.  330 uF polypropylene are available.  See WIMA DC-link capacitors for example.  But they going to be large and expensive I am sure.  I have never needed a DC link cap so I don't have details.  However, you might get away with a better electrolytic.  Something with a lower ESR than the cap you are using now.

Comment: Forgot...since this is AC, you will need two caps back to back if polarized:  --)|--|(--

Comment: frequency is changing, it is between 100Hz - 2500Hz, capacitors are also changing according to frequency.
@RobertEndl only specs of the circuit is frequency with capacitor values to get a sinusoidal magnetic waveform. I connect ceramic Cap in series with my capacitors and it worked. But this time, i decreased the Capacitors value coz series connected. So it is hard to find 330uF ceramic or polyproplene, any solutions that can keep my 1uF, 10uF.. my capacitors values constant ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use polarized capacitor because they will, in this circuit be fed an AC voltage. It's quite simple to prove. Think about the inductor - it must have an average voltage of zero across it. If it didn't then infinite current would flow. So based on this fact, the voltage at the drain of the mosfet MUST rise up to nearly twice the supply rail and back down to nearly 0V. Hence you have AC applied to a polarized capacitor. If you had good power rails you could put the polarized capacitors from drain to 0 volts, but there's another problem.

The ESR (effective series resistance) of an electrolytic capacitor (if that is what is being used) is quite high and this will ruin the Q factor expectations you may have i.e. the circuit is very inefficient at delivering a magnetic field from the inductor.

Comment: @FiratDagkiran did this give you the information you needed to understand the problem?